# Get the outgoing email Server Settings using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to return information about outgoing email server setting from Central Admin. I manage to return the outbound SMTP server information using the following:

`(Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | Where { $_.IsAdministrationWebApplication } ) | %{$_.outboundmailserviceinstance.server}`

However, I need to find out how to return value 'From Address', 'Reply-To address', and 'Character set'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
get-spwebapplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | where {$_.isAdministrationWebApplication} | select *outbound*
```

You will see several properties, including OutboundMailReplyToAddress, OutboundMailSenderAddress and OutboundMailSenderAddress.

OutboundMailSenderAddress is the 'From Address'
OutboundMailSenderAddress should be the character set:
 [When you configure e-mail settings, one of the settings you specify is the character set (also called "codepage") to use in e-mail messages. The default character set is 65001 (Unicode UTF-8)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288104(v=office.12).aspx)

[image]